# Generating the custom log file in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and Python. We have the following requirements.

Writing logs given in the playbook. Like

```
   tasks:
   - name: Copying the files
     copy:
       src: some path
       dest: some path
     write_log:
       msg: "Copied the files"
```

The 'write_log' should have the following:

1. Custom message given in the playbook.
2. Output of builtin 'copy' module.

We have tried custom callback plugin and achieved the second requirement to get the output of the 'copy' module, but unable to get custom message given in the playbook.

Kindly suggest how can we combine both.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html

Comment: It is talking about whether to show/hide the logs.